# Embedding Javascript in Google.sites

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I have tried embedding this code in a google site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Scrumbelina XP</title>
</head>
<body onload="updateScore()">
    <h1>Scrumbelina XP: <span id="score"></span></h1>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">


    function updateScore() {
      
    document.cookie = "XP=0"
      var x = document.cookie
      .split(';')
      .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
      .reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) =>
      ({ ...accumulator, [key.trim()]: decodeURIComponent(value) }),
    {});

    var XP = Number(x.XP);
    XP += 3;
    document.cookie = `XP=${XP}`;

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = Number(XP);
    }

</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

This should update the html span with id="score" to display the value of XP = 3.

Instead it displays the value of XP = NaN

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser console, if any?